# Can François Fillon be replaced as candidate of The Republicans to the presidential elections?

Tags: primaries, france

Few months ago, [François Fillon was elected candidate of the right wing party The Republicans in France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Republicans_(France)_presidential_primary,_2016) to the [presidential elections in 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_presidential_election,_2017).

These days, however, he is facing severe problems due to allegedly get a fake job for his wife worth almost one million euros:

- [François Fillon faces fresh claims over paying wife and children](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/jan/31/francois-fillon-faces-fresh-claims-over-paying-wife-and-children)
- [François Fillon faces call to explain payments to wife from MP funds](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/jan/25/francois-fillon-faces-call-explain-payments-wife-mp-funds-france)

The police is investigating the issue ([Police raid French parliament in François Fillon investigation](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/jan/31/french-parliament-raid-police-francois-fillon-investigation-penelope)) and some mention that his candidacy is under risk.

What would happen if he renounced? Would Alain Juppé, the defeated candidate in the primaries, be chosen automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an on-going problematic, so a lot about what is going to happen are speculations.

However, for the moment, official candidacies to the presidential elections haven't started. They have to be done [between February the 23rd and March the 17th](http://presidentielle2017.conseil-constitutionnel.fr/calendrier-dix-etapes-cles-de-lelection-presidentielle/). So, the rules that apply are those of The Republicans' party.

Also, [Fillon said he would renounce if an official investigation is launched](http://www.lemonde.fr/election-presidentielle-2017/article/2017/01/26/francois-fillon-renoncera-a-la-presidentielle-s-il-est-mis-en-examen-dans-l-affaire-de-l-emploi-suppose-fictif-de-sa-femme_5069771_4854003.html) (for the moment it is only a preliminary one). It is not clear whether he meant that he will only renounce in that case, or if in that case he will definitely renounce.

Now, [Alain Juppé said he wouldn't present himself if M. Fillon renounced](http://www.lepoint.fr/presidentielle/juppe-refuse-definitivement-d-etre-un-recours-si-fillon-se-retire-27-01-2017-2100488_3121.php). The official rules of the primaries dictate that another vote should take place, but it seems unlikely that they can book 10 000 voting booths in such a minimal time frame. So it seems likely that the party officials or some kind of committee decides who should be the party's candidate. (Sorry, I can't find the source where I read that.)

Comment: OK, thanks, so the issue here has to do with The Republicans' rules. Do you know if they have any kind of procedure for such cases?

Comment: [An article I just read](http://www.liberation.fr/elections-presidentielle-legislatives-2017/2017/02/01/fillon-le-parti-lr-proche-de-la-rupture_1545705) mentions that there are no rule in such a case.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. Yes, I see it mentions _Les règles ne prévoyant aucune issue en cas de désistement, ne restent que de mauvaises solutions._ so it is going to be a big problem that will need a lot of negotiation.

Comment: So he could have been replaced, but he was not.